# CmdletBinding() Won't Run in Azure Pipeline Powershell Task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-cmdlet, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a powershell script which executes perfectly when run from a Powershell commandline. I however need to incorporate this script into an Azure Pipeline (Classic) powershell Task, but it just won't run and is persistently erroring on the CmdletBinding method.

Immediately below is a snippet of the lines of code which is failing and further down is a screenshot of the error I'm getting.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, HelpMsg = "The environment short codes array. Defaults to 'dev', 'qa', 'sit', 'uat' & 'pre' ")]
    [string[]] $Environments = @('dev', 'qa', 'sit', 'uat', 'pre', 'prod')
)
```

[image]

Any idea how I can get round this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> ````yaml
>     [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, HelpMsg = "The environment short codes array. Defaults to 'dev', 'qa', 'sit', 'uat' & 'pre' ")]
>     [string[]] $Environments = @('dev', 'qa', 'sit', 'uat', 'pre', 'prod') ) ```
> ````

There is no parameter Attribute property named `HelpMsg` in Parameter Attribute object in ParameterAttributeClass. You can update the pipline instead  `HelpMsg` property with `HelpMessage` as shown in below which worked in local environment.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $false,
    HelpMessage= "The environment short codes array. Defaults to 'dev', 'qa', 'sit', 'uat' & 'pre'"
)]
[string[]] $Environments = @('dev', 'qa', 'sit', 'uat', 'pre', 'prod')
)
```

You can set the following properties with the [ParameterAttribute object](https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/):

```
HelpMessage                     Property   string HelpMessage {get;set;}
HelpMessageBaseName             Property   string HelpMessageBaseName {get;set;}
HelpMessageResourceId           Property   string HelpMessageResourceId {get;set;}
Mandatory                       Property   bool Mandatory {get;set;}
ParameterSetName                Property   string ParameterSetName {get;set;}
Position                        Property   int Position {get;set;}
ValueFromPipeline               Property   bool ValueFromPipeline {get;set;}
ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName Property   bool ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName {get;set;}
ValueFromRemainingArguments     Property   bool ValueFromRemainingArguments {get;set;}
```

Here is the reference [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-12?view=powershell-7.1#1237-the-parameter-attribute) , discussing about each property of ParameterAttribute with Sample example.